# How to improve the Billiard ball. Blender file is shared

Tags: rendering

Complete newbie here.. I'm trying to make a billiard ball. But am facing a few difficulty: Here's the blender file: [image]

(1) The letter 5 is not coming in render in the colour that it's visible in viewport. In the render it is coming as checkerboard colour.. How do i make the letter in black colour in the render too..

(2) When viewed in viewport, the ball looks nicer with the reflections.. but in the render, its not nice looking.. how do i make it better in the render..?

(3) No matter how many times i'm applying the modifier edge split on the smaller sphere on which the letter has been pasted, the edges do not look better.. How do i make the edges look better ?

I'm working in Blender 3.3.1 on windows 10
Here's the screenshot when the billiards ball is in viewport:
[image]

Here's the rendered output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the reflection, you are currently in *Material Preview*, which uses default HDRI images, if you switch to *Rendered Preview*, which will show your real environment, you won't see any reflection if your world has no HDRI. So give an HDRI to your world:

[image]

For the 5, you need to disable its *Holdout* option, which makes it transparent:

[image]

For the edges looking bad, your topology is bad, you need to recreate it with a UV sphere for example. By the way you could use much less faces than you do for your spheres and use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to make them look round:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1- the letter is not showing in render because you somehow checked the holdout button. Make sure it's disabled
[image]

2- The reflections you see in the viewport are caused by the hdri of the preview mode
[image]
to see how it will look in the render, click this button

[image]

you can make a custom world with an hdr map to get nicer reflections

[image]

3- The edge split modifier will separate the edges that have a certain angle. It wont be usefull in your case, instead make the topology cleaner for example project a filled circle on you sphere with a shrinkwrap modifier

[image]

Here is the file I fixed if you want to compare with yours
[image]